# Sync FireFox sessions without closing FireFox

Tags: firefox, sync, session, session-restore, session-manager

I've read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31430906/how-to-sync-session-manager-sessions-accross-devices-in-firefox but it requires FireFox to be closed so session files are synced and reloaded.

Is there any way to keep a FireFox's window's session synced, in a way that without closing FireFox it identifies that tabs had changed in another device and updates itself?

Or, at least, it keeps saving files as we change tabs, so that we keep a historical backup and are able to restore it when FireFox crashes and session is lost?

Comment: There exists other extensions that let you manually initiate the open tab syncing procedure.

Comment: I searched for some but found none that did what I need. Could you point me one plz?

Comment: If I recomended one I would have to vote to close this question.

Comment: Well I already searched and found none. If there is one that would solve my need, I'd like to know. After the question is answered, I don't mind it being closed. I'd rather have it closed and have a solution than have it opened with no help.

Comment: Having lots of closed questions doesn't sit well with the formula that determines if you can post questions.

Comment: hmm I didn't know that. tnx anyway